# How can I insert a new column in an Excel spreadsheet with Perl?

Tags: excel, perl

In Perl I am attempting to create a new column within my 'Book1.xls' excel file. I would like to create a new column in the 'E' column section and shift everything to the right like you normally would do when creating a new column. I am using the older 'xls' excel format because it's working for what I need it to do.

**[After running script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1AHb.png)<-if you look at this image you can see that the data in column E copied to column F. I would like to have the info in column E shift to column F and leave column E blank. How can I do that?**

I am using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://perldoc.pl/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://perldoc.pl/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) modules. I have my code below showing my attempt to create a new column.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->Parse('Book1.xls');
my $ws = $workbook->worksheet(0);

my $target_col = 4; #Column E
my $max_col = $ws->col_range();

for my $col ($max_col, $target_col, -1){
   for my $row (1 .. $ws->row_range()){
      my $cell = $ws->get_cell ($row,$col);
      if ($cell){
         my $parser2 = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
         my $workbook2 = $parser2->Parse('Book1.xls');
         my $wb2 = $workbook2->SaveAs('Book1.xls');
         my $worksheet2 = $wb2->sheets(0);

         $worksheet2->write($row, $col + 1, $cell->value());
         $wb2->close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *" ..and leave column E blank"* : To clear a cell you can `$worksheet->AddCell($row, $col, '');`

Comment: *"for my $col ($max_col, $target_col, -1){ ... }"* : This look syntax is not valid. Instead use `$worksheet->row_range()` and `$worksheet->col_range()` to find the minimum and maximum row and columns